# HDFS: does -mv erase old directory?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I just used `hdfs dfs -mv /folderA /folderB`, but I forgot that there are files in `folderB`.

When the move is complete, there is nothing inside `folderB`. How can I find the old files inside `folderB`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did a quick test of this scenario and this is what happens. When you perform mv, the destination directory or files in the destination directory are not deleted but the new files/directories are appended in the destination directory.

Please see below,

======

**Before `hdfs dfs -mv`:**

***List of files under `/FolderA` and `/FolderB`:***

```
[root ~]# hdfs dfs -ls /FolderA
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup          0 2019-09-18 12:52 /FolderA/file1.txt
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup          0 2019-09-18 12:52 /FolderA/file2.txt

[root ~]# hdfs dfs -ls /FolderB
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup          0 2019-09-18 12:52 /FolderB/file3.txt
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup          0 2019-09-18 12:53 /FolderB/file4.txt
```

======

***Execution of `hdfs dfs -mv` command:***

`[root ~]# hdfs dfs -mv /FolderA /FolderB`

======

**After `hdfs dfs -mv`:**

***List of files under `/FolderA` and `/FolderB`:***

```
[root ~]# hdfs dfs -ls /FolderB
Found 3 items
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2019-09-18 12:52 /FolderB/FolderA
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup          0 2019-09-18 12:52 /FolderB/file3.txt
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup          0 2019-09-18 12:53 /FolderB/file4.txt

[root ~]# hdfs dfs -ls /FolderA
ls: `/FolderA': No such file or directory
```

======

So, by looking at this, it looks like if you see no files under /folderB, there were no old files in the directory even before /folderA.

Hope this helps!